How to use variable with #[cfg(...)] attribute?
I would like to use some code only in Debug mode for assertion purposes. I have something like this at the moment:
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
let mut thing_initialized = false;

for ... {
    if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
        if expensive_check() { thing_initialized = true; }
    }
}

if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
    assert(thing_initialized);
}

But when the cfg is false, I get this error on all the lines thing_initialized is used on:
error[E0425]: cannot find value `thing_initialized` in this scope

What would be the right way to go about this? I could probably just write a proc macro and conditionally generate the expression from that, but seems like overkill. Is there a standard Rust method to achieve this? Or a common library that does the proc-macro thing already?

Instead of if cfg!(debug_assertions) below, just use #[cfg] on a block:
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
let mut thing_initialized = false;

for ... {
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    {
        if expensive_check() { thing_initialized = true; }
    }
}

#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
{
    assert(thing_initialized);
}


OH WTF. I tried that without wrapping in a block and got "attributes on expressions are experimental", so I just assumed that would occur WITH a block expression too since, well, it's an expression as well?? But I guess not, thanks!!
